# C# Add-In (VSTO .NET): Add domain name to outlook junk-email list

Tags: vsto

With the Outlook UI you can add an email address to your junk-email list, you can add a domain name as trusted domain, but you can't add a domain name to your junk-email list. You must manually edit the email address in your junk-email list to achieve that, so I wrote an Add-In to do this for me, but cant find the method to do that. Apparently the Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

Is there a code workaround for this fatal limitation?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Outlook Object Model does not provide any means to access or manipulate Junk Email settings.

You can try to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) to build the MAPI server side rule that lists all the blocked senders, but it is definitely not for the faint-hearted.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOJunkEmailOptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdojunkemailoptions.htm) object (returned from [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`JunkEmailOptions`, [RDOAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm).`JunkEmailOptions`, [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).`JunkEmailOptions`), which allow to add blocked senders using `RDOJunkEmailOptions.BlockedSenders.Add`.